# simple while loop excercise

Tags: java, loops

im learning java and currently im stuck on one exercise in which i cannot comprehend why is code behaving this way. Im tracing my steps on paper, but i would expect different answer than program actually does. If anyone could please explain why it does what it does

CODE:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
int numb = in.nextInt();

   while (in.hasNextInt())
   {
      System.out.println(numb);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      numb = in.nextInt();    
   }
```

TESTER is just entering numbers, so output should look like this:

```
Enter an integer: 5  
- 5 
- Enter an integer: 10 
- 10 
- Enter an integer: 8 
- 8 
- Enter an integer: k
...
```

But it looks like this:

```
Enter an integer: 5 
- 10 
- 5 
- Enter an integer: -4 
- 10 
- Enter an integer: 8 
- -4 
- Enter an integer: -6
- 8 
- Enter an integer: 11 
- -6 
- Enter an integer: -1
```

Comment: Basically, `hasNextInt` looks _ahead_ to see if the _next_ `nextInt` would be possible; it doesn't look behind to see if the previous `nextInt` worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you use `in.hasNextInt()` too soon (or too late, depending on how you look at it): the `Scanner` cannot tell you if it sees an integer or not until *after* the end user has entered a value.

If you prompt for a number and then check for `hasNextInt`, your code should not skip the second prompt:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int numb = in.nextInt();    
    System.out.println(numb);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
}
```

This would also prevent an exception in situations when the very first entry is not a number.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answering me, but somehow i still don't undestand it completely, maybe i am looking at it wrong. Is the imput of a scanner "scanned"in line int numb = in.nextInt(); ? If so, how can the first loop condition be measured, if in that point, scanner haven't scanned for user imput yet, and it doesn't know if it is int or not.

Comment: @user3338991 Did you try running this code? What results did you get?

Comment: I got the correct result, thank you for that, but as i am trying to learn java, im trying to understand why, which evades me for the moment.

For example if I enter letter instead of int, why this code doesn't print it, the scann and print are inside of loop and no condition is between them.

Perhaps i don't understand sequence in what java executes? Could you please go step by step of that code? Thank you

Comment: @user3338991 Although there's no condition between the `nextInt` and the print, the scanner already knows that `nextInt` would succeed, because it knows that the loop condition holds. When you call `hasNextInt` and get a `true` back, the scanner already has that `int`, it just haven't given it to you, because you didn't ask. The condition inside a `while` loop is a real condition, it is checked before the first entry, and each time the control goes back to the top of the loop. So you can retrace this with paper and pencil - prompt, check, scan, print, prompt, check, scan, print, prompt, etc.